# How to pivot existing dataframe in chunks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 10million row, 60 column dataframe that I read in from a parquet file.

I have a the line of code (below) that pivots my dataframe plus does 3 other lines of manipulation exactly how I need it. However this line of code only works on smaller datasets, not the larger dataset:

```
pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(df.fillna('missing'), index=cols, columns='Field', values='Value', aggfunc='first').reset_index().replace('missing', np.nan)

pivoted_df = pivoted_df.drop(['FieldId', 'FieldType'], axis=1)
pivoted_df = pivoted_df.replace('nan', np.nan)
pivoted_df = pivoted_df.groupby('Id', as_index=False).last()
```

Is there anyway I can chunk the data from `df`, while pivoting the chunks individually, cleaning and joining the pivoted data all together later?

kernel keeps crashing both in spyder and terminal.

Open to use any other tools to do this.

Comment: You can use the `chunksize` kwarg in [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: @Alex reading the data into the frame is no problem, its only at the pivot_table line do things fail.

Comment: By using the chunksize kwarg you can iterate over each chunk.

Comment: `chunksize` is not working for me when I pass it to `kwargs` in `read_parquet`. `read_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kwargs'`

Comment: Ah didn't realize you were using a different pandas read function. Looks like you can [pass kwargs to the engine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_parquet.html) so you may want to google which engine will allow you to chunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I broke up the dataframe into evenly sized pieces using:

```
import numpy as np
z = np.array_split(df, 5)
```

then iterated over the list:

```
for i in z:
   (rest of code)
```